# Warning: macro 'AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT' not found in library

Tags: software-installation, compiling, audio, git

I'm trying to install [soundconverter](https://github.com/kassoulet/soundconverter) via git. This is what I did in Terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install git
$ git clone https://github.com/kassoulet/soundconverter.git
$ cd soundconverter 
$ ./autogen.sh
```

And here is the output from running `/home/USERNAME/soundconverter/autogen.sh`

```
*** WARNING: I am going to run 'configure' with no arguments.
*** If you wish to pass any to it, please specify them on the
*** './autogen.sh' command line.

configure.ac:22: warning: macro 'AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT' not found in library
aclocal: installing 'm4/intltool.m4' from '/usr/share/aclocal/intltool.m4'
aclocal: installing 'm4/nls.m4' from '/usr/share/aclocal/nls.m4'
./autogen.sh: 27: ./autogen.sh: glib-gettextize: not found
```

Comment: And I had gettext installed before.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Researching missing package

As you kind of picked up on this is your issue:

```
configure.ac:22: warning: macro 'AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT' not found in library
aclocal: installing 'm4/intltool.m4' from '/usr/share/aclocal/intltool.m4'
aclocal: installing 'm4/nls.m4' from '/usr/share/aclocal/nls.m4'
./autogen.sh: 27: ./autogen.sh: glib-gettextize: not found
```

This message is telling you that you're missing a library. The internal logical name that this library goes by is this: `AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT`.

Searching for that will lead you to many threads like this one:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1131769

#### APT

Before we start looking, lets make sure our `apt-file` cache is updated:

```
$ sudo apt-file update
```

Now let's see what APT about this:

```
$ apt-file search glib-gettextize
libglib2.0-dev: /usr/bin/glib-gettextize
libglib2.0-dev: /usr/share/man/man1/glib-gettextize.1.gz
libglib2.0-doc: /usr/share/doc/libglib2.0-doc/glib/glib-gettextize.html
```

Good so the package's name is `libglib2.0-dev`. This jives with what our previous Google search were returning.

We can poke at this package to see if it has the `.m4` file that we appear to be missing:

```
$ apt-file list libglib2.0-dev | grep '.m4$'
libglib2.0-dev: /usr/share/aclocal/glib-2.0.m4
libglib2.0-dev: /usr/share/aclocal/glib-gettext.m4
libglib2.0-dev: /usr/share/aclocal/gsettings.m4
```

Good, so there's an `.m4` macro file that is what `configure` was looking for. 
So lets install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y libglib2.0-dev
```

**NOTE:** Once it's installed you can query installed packages using `dpkg`:

```
$ dpkg-query -L libglib2.0-dev | grep m4
/usr/share/aclocal/glib-2.0.m4
/usr/share/aclocal/gsettings.m4
/usr/share/aclocal/glib-gettext.m4
```

#### References

- [How do I get a list of installed files from a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package)
- [autogen.sh fails #27](https://github.com/Maato/volumeicon/issues/27)

Comment: wonderfully answered. this method of searching for packages that contain the missing library is new to me.

Comment: I did build automake, installed it to a random dir and then created a symbolic link to glib-gettext.m4 in /usr/share/aclocal. Yet, when I rerun autogen.sh of a random program, the error message: "configure.ac:19: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT" persists.